# Valid network configs for eth0 and wlan0

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface

I have a device that has two network interfaces eth0 and wlan0, I want the user to be able to freely configure both interfaces as static / dhcp

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address X.X.X.X
netmask X.X.X.X
gateway X.X.X.X

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wireless_mode managed
    wireless_essid any
    wpa-driver nl80211
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address X.X.X.X
netmask X.X.X.X
gateway X.X.X.X
    wireless_mode managed
    wireless_essid any
    wpa-driver nl80211
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

above, sample configurations for dhcp and static in /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0 (wlan0)

Unfortunately, I have a problem, if I have static IP set on both interfaces, then only if eth0 is connected, wlan0 will get ip.
How to solve such a problem I know for sure that there can be no gateway configured at the same time on both interfaces

Answer (score 0):

I make assumption that your device use modern Debian. If that is the case I suggest to switch to use modern systemd-networkd. Configuration syntax is different. I noticed that old ifupdown system you use have unexplained issues in new Debian 11.5. The ifupdown configuration is translated to systemd, that probably introduce problems.

check your configuration using:

```
networkctl -a status
```

**references on systemd-networkd:**

https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/systemd.network.5.en.html

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-networkd